# Jupyter on Kubeflow more unstable than locally - even with better specs

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kubeflow

I'm trying to run some SciKit-Learn training in a Jupyter Notebook running on (Charmed) Kubeflow. I've done the same training locally on my Windows laptop also on a Jupyter Notebook, and it works well. I try to run the same on Kubeflow Jupyter (with the notebook instance having better specs than my laptop, the latter having a 4-core CPU and 16GBs of ram, and the KF notebook - not Kubeflow generally, the specific notebook server - having 8 cores and 20GBs assigned to it).

From what I've searched around here on SO and Google, the logs showing `AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports` probably means I'm running out of memory. But on Windows I have less memory, and the training runs fine, just slower.

If this question is inappropriate or not formulated correctly, please give feedback in a comment about what to do before reporting, I'll modify or delete accordingly. Thank you!

What can cause such behavior (the kernel stopping when I try to re-run the training cell) and why does it work under Windows but not Kubeflow? For reference, this is the code I'm running:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV if models:
    del(models) models = []

# Iterate through each target variable for target in target_cols:
    # Create a random forest classifier
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(verbose=1)

    # Set up the hyperparameter search space
    param_distributions = {'n_estimators': [10, 50, 100, 200],
                           'max_depth': [None, 10, 20, 30],
                           'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10]}

    # Create a randomized search object
    search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_distributions=param_distributions, n_iter=10, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
    

    # Fit the model to the data
    #with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    search.fit(X_train, y_train[target])
    
    models.append(search.best_estimator_)
    
    print(f"Search complete for column {target}, with a best score of: {search.best_score_}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Azure Ubuntu VMs don't supply a swapfile by default. Enabling a swapfile on Ubuntu solves the issue.